# How to copy files recursively, rename them but keep the same extension in Bash?

Tags: bash, find, cp

I have a folder with tens of thousands of different file types. Id like to copy them all to a new folder (Copy1) but also rename them all to $RANDOM but keep the extension intact. I realize I can write a line specifying which extension to find and how to name it, but there is got to be a way to do it dynamically, because there are at least 100 file types and may be more in the future.

I have the following so far:

```
find ./ -name '*.*' -type f -exec bash -c 'cp "$1" "${1/\/123_//_$RANDOM}"' -- {} \;
```

but that puts the random number after the extension, and also it puts the all in the same folder. I cant figure out how to do the following 2 things:

1 - Keep all paths intact, but in a new root folder (Copy1)

2 - How to have name be $RANDOM.extension, instead of .extension.$RANDOM

PS - by $RANDOM i mean actual randomly generated number. I am interested in keeping folder structure, so we are dealing with a few hundred files at most per directory, but all directories/files need to be renamed to $RANDOM. Another way to look at what I need to do. Copy all contents or Folder1 with all subdirectories and files to Folder2 (where Fodler2 is a $RANDOM name), then rename all folders and files to random names but keep all extensions.

EDIT: Ok i figured out how to rename and keep extension. But I have a problem where its dumping all of the files into the root directory where script is run from. How do I keep them in their respective folders? Command Im using is:

```
find ./ -name '*.*' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" $RANDOM.${1##*.}' -- {} \;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Random is a 15-bit integer (0-32k). You're going to have collisions, and with "tens of thousands" of files, you could well run out of random numbers entirely.

Comment: do you need to handle nested folders?

Comment: Well, I am keeping the folder structure, its no more than like a hundred files per folder, so should not be any collions. 

Basically the result should be like this


Original folder with subfolders and files untouched. New folder created as a root, with entire directory structure and files of original folder copied. HOWEVER eveyr file and folder is renamed to random numbers or letters (doesnt matter).

Comment: I think you might get a better answer if you checked and updated your question... first you say you have `a folder` then you start talking about multiple subfolders - which? Then you say you have tens of thousands of file types, then `at least 100` - which? How about showing us a few filenames and some structure followed by how it should end up?

Comment: Just curious: What's the point of replacing file names by random numbers? I have trouble imagining a usecase where I would want that. Renaming files according to a given regex replacement pattern, ok, but throwing away the file name entirely?

Comment: You may want to look at `uuidgen` instead of $RANDOM if you have lots of files... http://ss64.com/osx/uuidgen.html

Comment: @Mark Sethell - Its one folder (a data set), that has folders inside of it, those folders have files and folders inside of them. All together its thousands of files.
cmaster - Its for testing a backup solution that will do a diff backup if files are the same. I essentially need to generate filler data, bu it still needs to be legit (not dummy files).

Answer (score 2):

> Ok i figured out how to rename and keep extension. But I have a
> problem where its dumping all of the files into the root directory
> where script is run from. How do I keep them in their respective
> folders? Command Im using is:
>
> ```
> find ./ -name '*.*' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" $RANDOM.${1##*.}' -- {} \;
> ```

Change your command to:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin find . -name '*.*' -type f -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" $RANDOM.${1##*.}' -- {} \;
```

Or alternatively using uuids instead of random numbers:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin find . -name '*.*' -type f -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" $(uuidgen).${1##*.}' -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with :

```
i=1
random="whatever"
find . -name "*.*" -type f | while read f
do
    newbase=${f/*./$random$i.} //added counter to filename
    cp $f /Path/Name/"$newbase"
    ((i++))
done
```

I had to add a counter to random (i), otherwise, if the extensions are similar, your files would overwrite themselves when copied.

In your new folder, your files should look like this :

```
whatever1.txt
whatever2.txt
etc etc
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Im doing this on MacOS, and when trying to use that code i get errors from cp command, it doesnt know what to do and gives me the help file for it. Also by $RANDOM i mean actual random value, not the word.

Comment: I re-edited accordingly, if the following doesn't work, then I don't know what to say...I just tried it on my comp and it worked fine. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: still doesnt work, are you using Linux to run it? or are you on MacOS?

I dont understand purpose of /Path/Name/ bit? It just needs to be root where script is.

Lets say there is a folder, with a folder1 inside it, with 10 files inside folder1. I need the sript to copy root folder and name it something random, then copy folder1 inside it but also name it something random, then copy all of the files inside but renaming each file to something random but keep the extension.

Comment: I guess another way to look at this... how about copying the whole thing to a new folder with a random name, then recursively changing name of every folder/file to random values? That would be same thing just in 2 steps instead of 1 where you would rename while copying. Just to reiterate, file/folder names can be anything, more random the better! As long as extension remains the same.

Comment: try adding cp -R to copy command, that copies the entire root directory, and all filenames will be changed to random. For path name, that's the location of your new directory, where everything is copied into. So if you are in your home directory, and have an empty folder called randomFolder, then you cp command will be -> cp -R $f randomFolder/"$newbase"

Comment: Note that, what find is doing here is extracting all the files in your root directory and from all its subdirectories, because you're specifying -type f

Comment: nope, still same errors. I am putting cp $f /"$newbase" and tried even just doing cp $f /blabla (so hardcoded name). Still same error. Seems like it has an issue with the line     newbase=${f/*./$random$i.}

PS - I do not need to extract files to anywhere.. Literally just drag and drop entire structure, then rename all files/folders. No moving anything anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67167/discussion-between-a-p-and-bolboa).

Comment: aha I would, but I've got to write an exam in 20 mins lol. I think I know what you want now though, i'll try and post a solution around 10 or 11.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command that worked for me.

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "{}" && cp "$1" ./$RANDOM.${1##*.}' -- {} \;
```